# mean() of column in pandas DataFrame returning inf: how can I solve this?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, precision

I'm trying to implement some machine learning algorithms, but I'm having some difficulties putting the data together.

In the example below, I load a example data-set from UCI, remove lines with missing data (thanks to the help from a previous question), and now I would like to try to normalize the data.

For many datasets, I just used:

```
valores = (valores - valores.mean()) / (valores.std())
```

But for this particular dataset the approach above doesn't work. The problem is that the mean function is returning `inf`, perhaps due to a precision issue. See the example below:

```
bcw = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data', header=None)

for col in bcw.columns:
    if bcw[col].dtype != 'int64':
        print "Removendo possivel '?' na coluna %s..." % col
        bcw = bcw[bcw[col] != '?']

valores = bcw.iloc[:,1:10]
#mean return inf
print  valores.iloc[:,5].mean()
```

My question is how to deal with this. It seems that I need to change the type of this column, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you not filter the `NaN` values out or set them to the mean first?

Comment: Thanks @ali_m for improving the English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not so familiar with pandas but if you convert to a numpy array it works, try

```
np.asarray(valores.iloc[:,5], dtype=np.float).mean()
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for, i changed all the valores dataset to float with `valores = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(valores, dtype=np.float))`, now i can calculate all the mean and standardize with `valores = (valores - valores.mean()) / (valores.std()) `. I guess this is not elegant, but is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If the elements of the pandas series are strings you get `inf` and the mean result. In this specific case you can simply convert the pandas series elements to `float` and then calculate the mean. No need to use numpy.

Example:

```
valores.iloc[:,5].astype(float).mean()
```

Comment: I think the issue can also happen if there's an overflow in the calculation of the mean. In my case, I have a `dtype: float16` that is returning `inf` for the mean. Adding your conversion solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

`NaN` values should not matter when computing the mean of a `pandas.Series`. Precision is also irrelevant. The only explanation I can think of is that one of the values in `valores` is equal to infinity.

You could exclude any values that are infinite when computing the mean like this:

```
import numpy as np

is_inf = valores.iloc[:, 5] == np.inf
valores.ix[~is_inf, 5].mean()
```

Comment: This was indeed the issue for me as well. Adding .replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan) before .mean() solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a column that was of dtype 'o', and whose max value was 9999. Have you tried using the `convert_objects` method with the `convert_numeric=True` parameter? This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason was an overflow: my original data was in `float16` and calling `.mean()` on that would return `inf`. After converting my data to `float32` (e.g. via `.astype("float32")`), `.mean` worked as expected.